# How to write array of objects in protractor javascript using filesaver and save output in xlsx format in local

Tags: javascript, excel, protractor, filesaver.js

I want to write array of objects of XLSX in Excel 2013 in protractor javascript and save excel output in xlsx format in D drive, i'm able to create file but saving in location is resulting anything.

Code i have used.

````
 workbook.Props = {
         Title: "SheetJS Tutorial",
         Subject: "Test",
         Author: "Red Stapler",
         CreatedDate: new Date(2017,12,19)
 };
 workbook.SheetNames.push("Test Sheet");
 var ws_data = [['hello' , 'world']];  //a row with 2 columns
 var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
 workbook.Sheets["Test Sheet"] = ws;
 var wbout = XLSX.write(workbook, {bookType:'xlsx',  type: 'binary'});
 function s2ab(s) {
     var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
     var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
     for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
     return buf;
     }
     var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {bookType: "xlsx"});
     FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "D:\\output.xlsx");```

array of object sample: 
[
{
 Col1: 'data1',
 Col2: 'data2',
 Col3: 'data3',
 Col4: 'data4',
 Col5: 'data5',
 Col6: 'data6',
 Col7: 'data7',
 Col8: '',
 Col8Datetime: 8,
 ColId: 'dataid1',
 EventType: 'Event3'
},
{
 Col1: 'datarow1',
 Col2: 'datarow2',
 Col3: 'datarow3',
 Col4: 'datarow4',
 Col5: 'datarow5',
 Col6: 'datarow6',
 Col7: 'datarow7',
 Col8: '',
 Col8Datetime: 8,
 ColId: 'dataid2',
 EventType: 'Event3'
}
] 

i'm not getting any error and Can you help me finding the location where the file is getting saved?
````

Comment: you can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: I have already installed using npm install in protractor node modules to work on it, could you please share code how to save xlsx file in a specific path.